# Sum(Offset(Cell(address - not working

Tags: indexing, sum, match, excel-2007, cell

Excel 2007 - I need to - find first non blank cell in row and then sum that and next 11 cells. Some of these 12 cells may be blank.
I have been using this formula which is not working:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(CELL("address",INDEX(B7:BI7,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B7:BI7),0))),0,12))
```

in this particular row the first populated cell is AM7 which is returned correctly in the CELL part of the formula above but obviously I have not put it together correctly.  Also it may be necessary to consider rows where the first value is within the last 12 columns and therefore there may be less than 12 columns to sum.  The table contains 1270 rows starting at row 7 and columns B to BI inclusive. Please could you tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: quite happy to change for different method if there is a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cell range can be constructed with a pair of [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) functions linked by a colon much the same as conventional, hard-coded cell ranges.

In A7 as a standard formula,

```
=SUM(INDEX(B7:BI7, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:BH)/(B7:BI7<>""), 1)):
     INDEX(B7:BI7, MIN(AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:BH)/(B7:BI7<>""), 1)+10, COLUMNS(B:BI))))
```

The [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) is used to provide the *position within* columns B:BI to start. A [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7) ensures that adding 10 to the start position (for the end position) will never exceed the number of columns in B:BI.

For pre-xl2010 installations, the AGGREGATE function's SMALL sub-function can be reproduced with an array formula².

In A7 as an array formula²,

```
=SUM(INDEX(B7:BI7, SMALL(IF(B7:BI7<>"", COLUMN(A:BH)), 1)):
     INDEX(B7:BI7, MIN(SMALL(IF(B7:BI7<>"", COLUMN(A:BH)), 1)+10, 60)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: sum_index_index]
   [image: sum_index_index2]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this